# Slide html content when clicking a button

Tags: jquery, html, slide

I am wondering if someone could help me with a jquery loop or script. When a button is clicked i woud like to animate a div to slide across the screen, when clicked again another div slides down. When the button is clicked AGAIN another div and so on, so on.

Here is the html mark up ive done so far

```
     <section id="1-text" class="horizontal-gallery-text">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis massa est, accumsan sed eleifend et, pulvinar sed lacus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam placerat enim et metus porta eu elementum augue ultricies. Fusce bibendum augue interdum neque fringilla at v</p>
    </section>


    <section id="2-text" class="vertical-gallery-text init-hidden">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis massa est, accumsan sed eleifend et, pulvinar sed lacus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam placerat enim et metus porta eu elementum augue ultricies. Fusce bibendum augue interdum neque fringilla at v</p>
    </section>


    <section id="3-text" class="horizontal-gallery-text init-hidden">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis massa est, accumsan sed eleifend et, pulvinar sed lacus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam placerat enim et metus porta eu elementum augue ultricies. Fusce bibendum augue interdum neque fringilla at v</p> 
    </section>
```

and javascript:

```
var totalslides = '3';
        var slidenum = 0;
        var slidenext = 0;
        var slideType = '';
        $(function(){
            $('#gallery-next').data('counter',1);
            $('#gallery-next').click(function() {
               slidenum = parseInt($('#gallery-next').data('counter'));
               slidenext = slidenum+1
               slideType = $('#'+slidenum+'-slide').attr('class')
               slideType = slideType.split('-')[0]
               if (slideType=='horizontal') slideType='up';
               else slideType = 'right';
                //alert('Next slideType is: ' + slideType)
                //hide(slide) is a jQueryUI function, so ensure you include that lib
               $('#'+slidenext+'-slide').delay(500).delay(500).show('slide',{direction:slideType}, 1000);
               $('#'+slidenum+'-slide').delay(100).fadeOut(100);
               slidenum = slidenum % totalslides + 1;
               $('#gallery-next').data('counter',slidenum);
            });
        });
```

So far its sliding a few of the slides however gets stuck on a few. Was wondering if anyone could see the problem or think of a better solution

Comment: Could you put this in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is, but I have a different way to do this.

I am assuming you want div 1 to slide right, then div 2 to slide down, then div 3 to slide right.

I use css3 transitions for this kind of thing, not jquery (I don't like jquery). You should have the following html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        section{
            position:relative;
            transition: all 0.1s;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var slidenum=0;
        window.onload=function(){
            var button=document.getElementById('gallery-next');
            button.onclick=function(){
                var curslide=document.getElementById(slidenum+'-slide');
                switch(slidenum++){
                    //replace the 700px with the value you want
                    case 1:curslide.style.top='700px';break;
                    case 2:
                    case 0:curslide.style.left='700px';break;
                }
                if(slidenum===3) button.addEventListener('click',function(){alert('we\'re already done')},false);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<sections> here-->
</body>
</html>
```

This is not tested